# Firebase Analytics - Disable, exlude some screens from automatic tracking. IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I like the feature of firebase, that swizzling UIViewController and automatically track screens. Also, I know that I can disable it with `FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled`. I don't want to disable them all, but just a few screens, that are containers.

I think by now this feature is not available. But maybe someone know a workaround how to exclude some screens from tracking.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is , you can use the method  - Analytics.setScreenName("HomeScreen", screenClass: "HomeVC") on the particular screens you want to track and leave the rest .